# WKWebView/UIWebView get website icon

Tags: ios, uiwebview, metadata, wkwebview, apple-touch-icon

How can I get the apple-touch-icon or logo of the website using WKWebView or UIWebView? I've read that getting a favicon is possible, however I plan on using the website's logo as a short cut like in iOS Safari and a favicon is too small for it. Is there a way to scrape metadata from a website in webView to get `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firefox for iOS we use a [User Script](https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios/blob/master/Client/Assets/Favicons.js) (Link to code on Github) to find the icon that then passes them back to the application which downloads them using [native code](https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios/blob/master/Client/Frontend/Browser/FaviconManager.swift) (Link to code on Github).

Comment: Thanks not only for the answer about getting the icon but also for linking me to firefox-iOS. I am developing a custom browser so it would be a great reference.