# Is it possible to get icon ready message by WKWebView?

Tags: cocoa, wkwebview

I could get this kinds of message in WebView by `(void)webView:didReceiveIcon:forFrame:`.
However, I can't find similar method in WKWebView so far.

Is it possible or should I use other way like below?
[WKWebView/UIWebView get website icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940693/wkwebview-uiwebview-get-website-icon)